# "DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message" when attempting to edit message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to edit a message that I sent with my bot a few days ago, but it won't let me edit it.

I'm sure it's because it's been about 7 days, but even so, I would like to know if there is a way to edit that message.

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (message.content === '!update-info') {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {
            return message.channel.send('Only server moderators can run this command!')
        }
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('734517639732396122');
        if (!guild) return console.log('Unable to find guild.');
        
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === '737363248126492772' && c.type === 'text');
        if (!channel) return console.log('Unable to find channel.');
        
        try {
            const messageedit = await message.channel.messages.fetch('815522275344252928');
            if (!message) return console.log('Unable to find message.');
        
             await messageedit.edit("__**Reacciona para activar notificacioness**__\n\n`Actualizaciones:` <:update:815505836880429087> \n`Twitter:` <:twitter:815505836842942474> \n`Facebook:` <:facebook:815505775278424084>\n`Instagram:` <:instagram:815505836608454667>");
            console.log('Mensaje de informacion actualizado.');
        } catch(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        message.delete();
    }
});
```

> DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message

> at RequestHandler.execute (/home/bungee/Discord-Bots/Uniito-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)

> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> at async RequestHandler.push (/home/bungee/Discord-Bots/Uniito-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)

> at async MessageManager._fetchId (/home/bungee/Discord-Bots/Uniito-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/MessageManager.js:135

> at async Client. (/home/bungee/Discord-Bots/Uniito-bot/client.js:105:33) {
> method: 'get',
> path: '/channels/738226897690820680/messages/815522275344252928',
> code: 10008,
> httpStatus: 404
> }

Comment: in your request to that channel - getting that message you're getting a 404 error.. That message doesn't exist.. It might have been deleted ? But the error is correct.. The API is telling you there is no message there.

Comment: also you're checking if `message` is defined after calling it.. Maybe you mean `messageedit` ?

Comment: No, the message has not been deleted, it is there.

Answer (score 2):

The error is correct, but you're not catching your error because you have a mixup in your logic.

```
        const messageedit = await message.channel.messages.fetch('815522275344252928');
        if (!message) return console.log('Unable to find message.');
```

I believe your if should be

```
        const messageedit = await message.channel.messages.fetch('815522275344252928');
        if (!messageedit) return console.log('Unable to find message.');
```

This case would check the response of the fetch request..